# Delete By Query vs Bulk Delete Request

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently, for deleting documents, what we do is

1. Fetch required documents by issuing a search request
2. Get their doc id
3. Issue a bulk delete request with all the doc ids.

Other way to do this is to issue a delete by query request.
However, delete by query can timeout as it's doing both querying and deletion with in the cluster.

Is the first approach more reliable than the second one?

Comment: the first approach requires more work and is essentially exactly what the delete by query approach does. The timeout you get probably has a cause that can be solved, but the second approach is clearly better in my opinion (at least from my experience).

Comment: I'm using AWS Elasticsearch. delete_by_query requests  (lot of matching docs) are usually returning GATEWAY_TIMEOUT because of the ELB they have infront of ES Service. I think one work around is to use wait_for_completion=false and then use task API to determine the status.